# Watcher in ZooKeeper does not trigger event when create mode is Sequential

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am new to ZK so not sure if this is true but during my testing i found the following:

```
   ZooKeeper zooKeeper1 = new ZooKeeper(
                hosts, // ZooKeeper service hosts
                5000,  // Session timeout in milliseconds
        // Anonymous Watcher Object
      watcher);
```

where watcher is a Watcher instance.

Now if I do this:

```
zooKeeper1.exists("/test13", watcher);
zooKeeper1.create("/test13", null, Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE, CreateMode.EPHEMERAL_SEQUENTIAL);
```

then even defined under watcher object is not triggered

But if do this:

```
zooKeeper1.exists("/test13", watcher);
zooKeeper1.create("/test13", null, Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE, CreateMode.EPHEMERAL);
```

then even defined under watcher object is triggered.

Basically if I use Sequntial as CreateMode it the event is not triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is really very simple,
When you use `EPHEMERAL_SEQUENTIAL` mode to create the `Znode` then the node which is created is not having the same name as a serial number is added, something like `/zoo/duck0000000027` when I created with name `/zoo/duck`
but on the other hand when you create the node `CreateMode.EPHEMERAL` then the node is created with same name as specified.

In `EPHEMERAL_SEQUENTIAL` scenario if you want to add `watcher`, then add the `watcher` after creating then node something like,

```
String createdPath = zooKeeper1.create("/test13", null, Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE, CreateMode.EPHEMERAL_SEQUENTIAL);
zooKeeper1.exists(createdPath, watcher);
```

Comment: Thanks dbw that works great. I had another question regarding zooKeeper. I have a requirement where i would be creating 3 instances of zookeeper clients on 3 different machines. So if i have a logic where i create a root node, then if 2 zookeeper clients invoke that logic together then one of them will throw exception since root node would have been created allready. In this case synchronization will not work coz they will be on different machines. I looked at multi feature that was introduced from 3.4 but as I see what it does is it will execute different operations in 1 transaction.

Comment: Adding to above, i meant like you can 50 new nodes to a root node but they all can be executed in one transaction rather than single command. But that does not solve my problem. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @sachinjain just read and understand the basics once again, For better info get an ebook `Hadoop.The.Definitive.Guide.3rd.Edition` and start reading `Chapter 14 ZooKeeper` for better info and understanding......